# how to enable google cloud beta build for a project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I got the below error when using gcloud beta build to create a worker pool:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.builds.worker-pools.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: project is not allowlisted for this feature, please contact Google Cloud Support at https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

So how can I allowlist my project to use this feature?

Comment: It's a private beta. It should be rolled out soon. If you have Google contact (Sales, Customer Engineer, Developer Advocate, Product Manager), you can ask him to be enrolled (your use case will be asked and, if relevant, you could be allowlisted)

Comment: Did you contact Google Cloud Support? Only Google can help you with `invite-only` features. However, Google is very good about getting customers on the list in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

As per the GCP documentation, if the error is related to PERMISSION you need to whitelisting the project by requesting this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdAkLtvPUQFCgAUcHUi1VDHn_GaQz_sDOvFxpg3JXIJdIZY6g/viewform). It might be taking 24-48 hours.